# removing multiple selections from JList

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, selection, jlist

I have a JList with some elements where multiple selection is allowed. Before these elements are added to the JList, some information about them is being stored in a static HashMap in a separate class. When more than 1 items are selected and the 'Remove selected' button is pressed, I am trying to remove the selected items (which works fine) and also delete their records from the HashMap. For some reason though, if I select more than 1 elements, only the first record in the HashMap is removed. I don't understand how this works for the JList but doesn't work for the HashMap. My code below:

```
remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    Object[] selectedElementsValues = jList.getSelectedValues();

                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedElementsValues.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println(jList.getSelectedValue().toString());
                        System.out.println(PersonClass.map.get(jList.getSelectedValue().toString()));

PersonClass.map.remove(jList.getSelectedValue().toString());

System.out.println(PersonClass.map);

                }
```

It works fine if I select only one item at a time and remove it. But not with multiple selection. The items from the JList are removed properly, though, so I don't see why it doesn't do the same for the map.

Thx

Comment: I think your problem is that remove in a map doesn't take an index wherease it does for a Jlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the loop that removes items from the map uses `jList.getSelectedValue().toString()`, when the `jList` selection is not modified. You can use the selection array you obtained earlier:

```
for (Object o : selectedValues) {
    PersonClass.map.remove(o.toString());
}
```

Note that `getSelectedValues()` is deprecated, and you should use `getSelectedValuesList()` instead.